# Drawing a distorted spiral Curve

Tags: bezier-curves, path

I'm sure this is not very complicated but I'm new in Blender and trying to figure out how to draw this curve I attached.
Basically the form will look like a circle from the top view and have this spirals going down with different density and directions.
What would be the best way to do this?

I appreciate all your replies.
Thank you
[image]

Comment: Check out spirals in the Add Curve Extras addon.

Comment: Thank you batFinger
I actually added those and it's helpful to create spiral curves etc. I need this form to go around a circle, meaning this is the side view of the form and when you look from the top view it appears like a circle. I just don't know how to contract and expand different parts of this spiral form with smooth transitions between them. 
Thank you very much for your reply again 
Appreciated